# Intel wireless 8265

Tags: wireless, intel

I've been using mac since the late 80's, and now considering a change tu Ubuntu.
Have bought a Xishan N250BU 15" as a "test machine".
Installed Ubuntu 16.04 (updatet to 4.4.0-49) and Gnome 3.20 as desktop environment.
My problem is WLAN. Intel 8265 combined Bluetooth/Wlan.
The funny thing is that Bluetooth is working, no Wireless.

As I am quite new to Linux, any tips is most appreciated.

Output of lshw:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Network controller
product: Intel Corporation
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
version: 78
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:df100000-df101fff
```

Output of lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5904 (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d12 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d58 (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 24fd (rev 78)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287 (rev 01)
03:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
```

Comment: Your wifi is supported in Ubuntu 16.10, see [bug reporting help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) if you wish to report a bug about Ubuntu 16.04 not supporting this device

Comment: Did a clean install of 16.10 (benefit of a test machine), and everything is working :-) Thanks